# Sql safe strings in java w/o prep'd statements

Tags: java, sql

Keeping **prepared statements aside**, Alternatively I want to "stay safe" from sql injection in java...

I thought of doing this (a htmlentity conversion) ?

```
suspectedInputvariable.replace("'","&#39;")
                      .replace(";","&#359;")
                      .replace("\"","&#34;");
```

is ***suspectedInputvariable***  now safe to be embedded with a sql query?

Comment: why would you want to keep prepared statements aside?

Comment: I wrote a separate class where i just issue a query and nothing more arguments

Comment: @everlasto: That's not a reason not to use a prepared statement.

Answer (score 3):

First, why would you want to do such a thing? The driver knows how to safely treat strings. Just use a `PreparedStatement`.

Second, you have to escape `\` and some other characters, too. If you handle all the characters listed here your code should be reasonably safe with MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html The list of characters for other databases may differ.

Comment: eager to know if possible w/o ppd stt .. and there are ways to escape backslashes too

Comment: Of course it is possible, but it's easy to get it wrong. For example PHP has *mysql_escape_string*, that mostly works, until someone figured out that it can be fooled by unicode strings. Now they recommend *mysql_real_escape_string.* The risk of having your database open to all imaginable queries is just too scary.

Comment: Thanks Joni, for now just have to escape only `\x00, \n, \r, \, ', " and \x1a` until someone figures out the next hack ;) ..   if i could find something than ppd stt, it will drastically reduce my time.. tats y im interested..

Comment: You could create the prepared statement once and hold it in a cache. They are meant to be reused with different parameters.. or does the sql itself vary? (list of fields, tables, where-conditions..)

Comment: @everlasto: it's hard to even imagine a scenario where prepared statements, correctly used, cause any significant performance problems.

Answer (score 2):

> is suspectedInputvariable now safe to be embedded with a sql query?

Probably not. There are all kinds of little-known features in various SQL dialects that could be used to circumvent this blacklist.

Just use prepared statements. Period.

Comment: so ppd stts seems to be the final destination :/